# Non-linear regime of matter power spectrum

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, astronomy

**Question 1**

I was trying to understand why cosmologist calculate the matter fluctuations in  spheres of  $8 h^{-1} Mpc$. I look for information and I  [find](https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Einasto/Einasto4_1.html)  that in this scale the fluctuations become non-linear, but I can't  understand how they conclude that. Why not calculate the matter fluctuations in spheres of $0.8h^{-1} Mpc$?

[image]
**Question 2**

Can be explained in a simple way (without calculations) how cosmologist calculate the matter power spectrum? Is the matter power spectrum product of observations or is a theoretical derivation?

Comment: The parameter of matter fluctuations in spheres of $8h^{-1} Mpc$ is usually known as $\sigma_{8}$.